# Uploading files using CURL

Tags: libcurl

curl -X POST -T D:\B.jpg –-header "Authorization:Bearer xxxxxxxxx http://www.sampleupload.com

I am trying to upload file using the above way.But the result is fail.

Please help

Comment: Please show the actual code you have tried so far, and explain what is failing.  Are you getting a libcurl error? An HTTP error?

Comment: it returns 302 http error code

Comment: 302 is a redirect to another URL.  Did you enable libcurl's [`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.html) option so it can process redirects?

Answer (score 0):

Hi all got it the answer :)

curl -L -H `X-Auth-Token:xxxxxxxxx' -F "file=@Bggg.jpg;filename=Bggg.jpg" http://www.sampleupload.com

thanks for the support,
Bilaal